# How to send bitcoin programatically using API? Bitcoin Transaction. (Without Setting Node)

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, bitcoin-wallet-app, bitpay

> Want to send BTC from one address to another address without using
>   JSON-RPC.

**Followed and used:**

1. https://bitcore.io/api/
2. https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcoin-transaction/v/1.1.1

2nd:bitcoin-transaction Working good for testnet but giving each time new errors for Mainnet.

**If anyone knows better way to send BTC, kindly let me know.**

Comment: Software recommendations are not in the scope of this website: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @JBaczuk Understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C#, I would use [NBitcoin](https://github.com/MetacoSA/NBitcoin) to generate raw transaction and push it to some API provider. This eliminates the need of setting up full node.